# How to return a value with observable when it becomes defined?

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I am wondering if there was way to wrap an observable around `sessionStorage.getItem('currentuser')` so calling code can subscribe and gets the value only after it is set in the `sessionStorage`

Is this possible?

Anand

Comment: Why are you thanking yourself in your own question?

Comment: Hahaha - that's a good one @Zachscs

Comment: But seriously sessionStorage is synchronous. Try localForage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. You could solve it this way with a Service

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

    private storageAlert: Subject<any> = new Subject('');
    private propagationIsBlocked: false;

    // use this blocker for option 3
    blockPropagation(): void {
        propagationIsBlocked = true;
    }

    // use this unblocker for option 3
    unblockPropagation(): void {
        propagationIsBlocked = false;
    }

    // subscribe to this method in order to get updated whenever a change happens
    getValue(): Observable<any> {
        return this.storageAlert.asObservable();
    }

    // trigger the update << option1
    setValue(value: any) {
        if(value){
            this.sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
            this.storageAlert.next(value);
       } 
    }

    // trigger the update << option2
    setValue(value: any) {
        if(value && value.id !== storageAlert.getValue().id){
            this.sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
            this.storageAlert.next(value);
       }
    }

    // trigger the update << option3
    setValue(value: any) {
        if(!this.propagationIsBlocked){
            this.sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
            this.storageAlert.next(value);
        }
    }
}
```

But honestly speaking, if you use this Service you do not need the sessionStorage or localStorage as the value is already stored in the Service's variable 'storageAlert'. And each Subscribing Instance gets the new value due to the subscription.

Comment: Hi @DiabolicWords, thanks for your response. I like the tip about using the storage from the service instead of sessionStorage. However I also  need a way to make a blocking call on subscribe so that the calling code  won't continue execution until the value is available. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi Anand. As far is I know, you only can subscribe or unsubscribe to an Observable. A 'don't provide'-state is not foreseen. But you can achieve this by implementing  a simple if-clause in the setter. I re-edited my code and suggest 3 different approaches to reach your goal. Maybe one of them is what you expect.

Comment: Hi DiabolicWords - thanks so much for illustrating. I wish I was able to make use of these. But I have to do this while app is bootstrapping so somewhere in that flow I really need to block so for that I still need to rely on sessionStorage